# Ionic 4: Background resize opening keyboard

Tags: ionic4

I've changed the background, modified the globals.scss and config.xml

globals.scss:

```
ion-content {
    --background: url('./assets/img/background.png') 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

config.xml:

```
<preference name="keyboardResize" value="false" />
<preference name="keyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
```

The background keeps scrolling when the keyboard is open. I'd really appreciate any kind of help to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will disable the scroll:

```
ion-content {
   --overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but even with **!important** tag, the background keeps scrolling.

Comment: @JuanOsorio this may help you https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/8#issuecomment-381118185

Comment: Thank you so much.